# Anyway to compare int to drawable?ANDROID

Tags: java, android, object, int

Is there anyway to compare s to a? In this code I have int s as the answer and if the `drawable == s` then I want to display a `"Correct!"` toast message. Any help would be appreciated.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
          int s = R.drawable.exitbtn;
          Resources res = getResources();
          Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.exitbtn);
          Object a=drawable;
          if(a==s)
          {
                ImageView imageview =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CORRECT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                btn1.setText("1");
                btn2.setText("2");
                btn3.setText("3");
                btn4.setText("4");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to 'compare' them? By what number the canvas looks like?

Comment: This is like comparing a NASA rocket to orange juice.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing a `Drawable` instance to an `int` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do? Do you want to check if the method `res.getDrawable(R.drawable.exitbtn);` returns the right object?

I think it's redundant to fetch an identifier from R-file:

```
int s = R.drawable.exitbtn;
```

Then fetch the object using the very same identifier:

```
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.exitbtn);
```

And then try to check whether it's really the right object by comparing ids.

I think that there's no place for mistake (specifically, confusion of an int value) when it comes to getting a Drawable by id. If you want to be sure the object has been created, check it against a null.

```
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.exitbtn);
if(drawable != null){
   //do stuff
} else {
   //handle the situation where there's no drawable
}
```

Also, I think there's no way to fetch an id from a Drawable object. The instance returned by `getDrawable` does not contain such information.

Better yet, you can use the fact that `getDrawable` can throw a `NotFoundException` if the id is somehow wrong. Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void MyClick(View view)
    {
     Drawable fDraw = view.getBackground();
     Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover);

      if(fDraw.hashCode() == sDraw.hashCode())
      {
       //Not coming
      }
    }
```

or use following code

> Use getTag() and setTag() for comparison