# Converting a ResourceId (Int) to a Drawable from SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, drawable, android-drawable

I am running into an issue where I would like to convert a ResID (Int Value) that I have stored into a SQLite DB into a Drawable. This drawable should be set as the picture associated with its "event object" that is being populated in a listview.

**What am I missing? Where should I be looking to convert the resId back into a Drawable to st it?**

NOTE: I am trying to do the conversion in EventAdapter Class.

**DatabaseHandler**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scheduleManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_EVENTS = "events";


// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EVENTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */


//adding an event (NEEDS TO ADD DRAWABLE)
 public void addEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, event.get_Id()); //Event ID
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, event.get_title()); // Event Title
        values.put(KEY_TIME, event.get_time()); // Event Time
        values.put(KEY_DATE, event.get_date()); // Event Date
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, event.get_image()); // Event RESOURCEID

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

   // Getting single contact
   public Event getEvent(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
               KEY_TITLE, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATE, KEY_IMAGE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
               new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.moveToFirst();

       Event event = new Event(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
               cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getBlob(4));
       // return contact
       return event;
   }


    // Getting All Contacts
   public List<Event> getAllContacts() {
      List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
      // Select All Query
      String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      // looping through all rows and adding to list
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {

              Event event = new Event();
              event.set_Id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
              event.set_title(cursor.getString(1));
              event.set_time(cursor.getString(2));
              event.set_date(cursor.getString(3));                          
              event.set_image(cursor.getBlob(4));
              eventList.add(event);
          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }

      // return contact list
      return eventList;
  }

// Getting event Count
    public int getEventsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

 // Updating single contact
    public int updateEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, event.get_title());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, event.get_time());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, event.get_date());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_EVENTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.get_Id()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_EVENTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.get_Id()) });
        db.close();
    }

 }
```

**EventAdapter**

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    //adding drawable to imageview
    ImageView img;
    TextView title;
    TextView time;
    TextView date;
}

public EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.date_detail);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Event event = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_detail, null);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);

        //adding drawable to imageview
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.title.setText(event._title);
    viewHolder.time.setText(event._time);
    viewHolder.date.setText(event._date);

    //convert from byte array to bitmap               
    Bitmap bitmap = convertByteArrayToBitmap(event._image);
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    // CONVERT BITMAP TO DRAWABLE
    viewHolder.img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(
        byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
ArrayList<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView ivPic;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;
int resId;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    // ///////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // ///////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();

    adapter.addAll(events);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            Bitmap bitmap = b.getParcelable("BITMAP");


            /////CONVERTING A BITMAP TO A BYTE[]
            byte[] image = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            image = bos.toByteArray();
            /////////




            // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
            /**
             * CRUD OPERATIONS
             */

            Log.e("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addEvent(new Event(0, title, time, date, image));

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.e("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            // List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();
            List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();
            adapter.addAll(events);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // logging all events

            for (Event ev : events) {
                String log = "Id: " + ev.get_Id() + " ,Title: "
                        + ev.get_title() + " ,Date: " + ev.get_date()
                        + " ,RESOURCEID: " + ev.get_image();
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.e("Name: ", log);

            }

            // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing the `int` value, why didn't you try to store the `byte[]` of the `Bitmap`?

Comment: Can you explain what's the issue exactly? The image doesn't load? Any error?

Comment: You can get this to work - but IMHO this is a really bad idea - you can run into issues e.g. when updating the app - if you really have to do it that way use the name of the resource and not the id - the name is in your hands - not the ID ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11683902/1188208) answer. Quoting its poster (@Tom), *I think there's no way to fetch an id from a Drawable object. The instance returned by getDrawable does not contain such information. Better yet, you can use the fact that getDrawable can throw a NotFoundException if the id is somehow wrong. Check the docs for details.* [Link to Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

So, my recommendation is to change the way that you are storing the image in your `SQLite Database`. The best way that I have found is using the `BLOB` type.

First let's change that implementation:

In your `DatabaseHandler`:

Change,

```
String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_RESID + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

to this:

```
String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_RESID + " BLOB" + ")";
```

**Also**: Make sure that the object `Event` is implemented to use `byte[]` (getters and setters) instead of that `int`. For instance, `event.get_resId()` should return a `byte[]` and, so on.

Then, to convert a `Bitmap` to a `byte[]` you would have to implement this code:

```
byte[] image = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
image = bos.toByteArray();
```

Now, you can add the `image` to your database.

In the same way, to convert the stored `byte[]` to a `Bitmap`, you would have to do this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Where should I be looking to implement "Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);" --- I am not sure where it is that I should decode the byte[]. --- I updated the source code to reflect the changes.

Comment: It could be anywhere. My suggestion is to pass the `byte[]` to the adapter and decode it in there before using the Bitmap

Comment: I was reading your code. It seems ok. You just need to change the constructor of the eventadapter and pass the byte array. Once there you can decode to a bitmap and a drawable to finish. Dont do it on the activityresult method.

Comment: I have a working version. Just running into an issue where the drawable is far to small when being displayed. Updated source code once again.

Comment: Try using setImageBitmap to see if it works. If not, that would be a different question :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not store ResourceId values in a database. They can change each time you add new module or library which has own generated files.